# Ionic app style not rendering properly

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have a problem with Ionic styling. I started a blank app and added some text and header styling.
The app launches well in the browser but the styles are not rendering as they should (larger text button and header background color not full). These problems won't appear anymore if I refresh the browser page.

[Screenshot of the first render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3IFZ.png)

[Screenshot after refresh, everything is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIWYz.png)

The source code is very simple as I juste edited a blank ionic app:

```
<ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title text-center class="headerStyle">
          Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="homeContentStyle" padding center>
    <ion-grid text-center>
        <ion-row style="margin-top:3%;">
            <ion-col>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <button class="homeButton" ion-button large>Testing</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
page-home {
        ion-grid {
        height: 80%;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .headerStyle {
        background: white;
        font-variant: small-caps;
    }

    .homeContentStyle {
        background: green;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 120%;
        color: white;

        img {
            width:7em;
            height:7em;
        }

        .homeButton {
            padding: 35px;
            margin:5%;
            width:70%;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 0px !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is, on the first render for the ion-navbar; it is getting a child div element with class

> toolbar-background-md

which has a

> background: #f8f8f8;

that's why the header background color is not full, but after reload you are using some apple device ( I'm guessing ) which doesn't have the class with any background. That's why after refresh everything gets fixed.

Same for the button. on the first render it gets a class called

> button-md

which has

> text-transform: uppercase;

that's preventing it from gettng

> font-variant: small-caps;

**Note** : the classes ending with

> -md

are added for android only.

**Things will be more clear to you if you run**

```
ionic serve --lab
```

[Screenshot for lab flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVT0W.png)

The following SCSS will solve your issue

```
page-home {
  ion-grid {
    height: 80%;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  ion-navbar {
    background: white;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    .toolbar-background {
      background: none;
    }
  }

  .homeContentStyle {
    background: green;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: white;

    img {
      width:7em;
      height:7em;
    }

    .homeButton {
      padding: 35px;
      margin:5%;
      width:70%;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 0px !important;
      text-transform: unset;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-header class="headerStyle">
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title text-center>
          Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

.homeButton {
            padding: 35px;
            margin:5%;
            width:70%;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 0px !important;
            font-size: 50px;
        }
```

Comment: Putting class in ion-header won't apply the header styling.
It's not a css problem as the style renders well after refresh.